# Laravel API call goes through even with session expired

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, single-page-application

I have a SPA based on Laravel 5.8 and Vue 2.0.

Everything is working fine, a little bit too much to be honest, because if I delete the session and I try to save the content afterward or keep navigating the private pages, every ajax call that I'm doing with Axios is going through without returning any error. Only if I forcefully refresh the page I get the error page I setup but if I don't, I can keep doing everything even if the session no longer exist.

This is my setup.

`web.php` is where I have the only php route that points to a `singlePageController`:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/{any}', 'SinglePageController@index')->where('any', '.*');
```

Then in the `singlePageController` I return the view:

```
class SinglePageController extends Controller
    {
        public function index() {
        return view('app', ['loggedUser' => auth()->user()]);
    }
}
```

Then I have the `api.php` where I have the API routes. As you can see at the end I have the middleware to make it private. Just to make an example this is the one I use for updating the content:

```
Route::put('event/update/{slug}', 'EventController@update')->middleware('auth:api');
```

Then the related controller of that API route:

```
public function update(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $event = Event::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $event->title = $request->input('title');

    return new EventResource($event);
 }
```

And in the end this is the Resource I use to define what and how the API data is going to be displayed:

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    // return parent::toArray($request);

    return [
        'id' => $this->id,
        'title' => $this->title,
        'slug' => $this->slug,
        'curator' => $this->curator,
        'featured_image' => $this->featured_image,
        'body' => $this->body,
        'date' => $this->date
    ];
 }
```

So this above is the flow I have. Then when I do an axios call to update the content, I'm doing something like:

```
    axios({
            method: 'PUT',
            url: '/api/event/update/' + this.$route.params.slug + '?api_token=' + this.isLogged.apiToken,
            data: dataToSave,
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })  
        .then((response) => {
            this.getNotification('Success: The Event has been saved');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            this.getNotification('Error: Impossible saving the event');
            console.log(error);
        })
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: When you say you "delete the session", how are you doing this specifically and how is authentication handled between the client and the backend? Are you using just API Tokens, JWT's etc?

Comment: I'm using just the basic Laravel Auth. No JWT or Passport. When I delete the session I'm just deleting it from the Chrome dev tool

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel routes in api.php ignore the session data.

If you want to authenticate with session data you could move your api routes to web.php and you should see the results you expect.

Comment: Now I can't save neither when I'm logged in LOL.... It tells me "405 Method Not Allowed" I'm using PUT as Request Method

Comment: Did you update your routes in vue to match the new location? The web routes don't use the /api/ prefix, like the api routes do.